# Querying wordpress with meta queries from Gatsby

Tags: wordpress, graphql, gatsby, wp-graphql

I'm trying to fetch data from my Wordpress backend using a meta query. I'm using this plugin:
https://www.wpgraphql.com/extenstion-plugins/wpgraphql-meta-query/

I can run my query in GraphiQL IDE in Wordpress, but not in Gatsbys GraphiQL tool.

I get this error:
Unknown argument "where" on field "Query.allWpPage"

Query:

```
query test {
  allWpPage(
    where: {metaQuery: {
      relation: OR,
      metaArray: [
        {
          key: "some_value",
          value: null,
          compare: EQUAL_TO
        },
        {key: "some_value",
          value: "536",
          compare: EQUAL_TO
        }
      ]
    }}
  ) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        uri
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried deleting the cache directory and rebuilding, didn't help.

And just to clarify, I have no problems running other queries and getting ACL-data and what not. The only problem I have (right now) is exposing the where argument to Gatsby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`where` filter is restricted in Gatsby. Here you have a detailed [list of comparators](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/query-filters/#comparator-details), but they are:

- `eq` (equals)
- `ne` (not equals)
- `in` (includes)
- `nin` (not includes)
- `lt`, `lte`, `gt`, `gte` (less than, equal or less than, greater than, equal or greater than respectively)
- `regex`, `glob` (regular expression)
- `elemMatch` (element matches)

On the other hand, there is a list of [filters available](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/graphql-reference/). In your case, [`filter`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/graphql-reference/#filter) is what you are looking for. Your final query should look like:

```
query test {
  allWpPage(
   filter : {uri : {ne : "" }}
  ) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        uri
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Of course, adapt the `filter` to your needs. `elemMatch` should work for you either.

You will need to add each condition for each property of the object you're trying to match.

---

### Why is `where` restricted?

Because it belonged to Sift, a library that Gatsby was using to use [MongoDB queries](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/), where `where` is available. Since [Gatsby 2.23.0](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/compare/gatsby@2.22.22...gatsby@2.23.0) (June 2020) this library is not being used anymore. More details at [History and Sift](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/query-filters/#history-and-sift):

> For a long time Gatsby used the Sift library through which you can use
> MongoDB queries in JavaScript.
>
> Unfortunately Sift did not align with how Gatsby used it and so a
> custom system was written to slowly replace it. This system was called
> “fast filters” and as of gatsby@2.23.0 (June 2020) the Sift library is
> no longer used.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, the field ("some_value" above) I want to filter on is an ACL field of type "post object". That field does not show up under "filter". It does show up with the fields I can select, so there's no problem with getting the field to show up in GraphQL. But I can't filter on it.

Comment: I'll set this as the accepted answer since it did answer my original question on how to make "where" visible in Gatsby. I'll formulate a new question for ny problem.